# how to store spark mllib model into local file system (windows)

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I am trying to save my Kmean cluster model into local file system . I am using Pyspark mllib for Kmean clustering.  However i am getting the following error.

```
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o46.save.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:E:/Work/Python1/work/spark/anomalydetectionspark/test/spark-warehouse
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:89)
```

my code:

```
  clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, 2, maxIterations=10,
                            runs=10, initializationMode="random")

    # Evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors
    def error(point):
        center = clusters.centers[clusters.predict(point)]
        return sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in (point - center)]))

    WSSSE = parsedData.map(lambda point: error(point)).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
    print("Within Set Sum of Squared Error = " + str(WSSSE))

    # Save and load model
    clusters.save(sc, "file:E:/Work/Python1/work/spark/anomalydetectionspark/test/spark-warehouse")
```

Can someone please help me to find why did i receive the error?

Comment: Something to do with the file path you're feeding to `clusters.save`; I'm not as familiar with file paths on Windows, but my suspicion is that you'd need to remove the `file:` prefix, so it's just `E:/path/to/file`.

Comment: @Magsol,  I tried that also. But still same error

Comment: Spark kmeans is about the slowest you will find. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute path of the model that you are using is not proper, instead of this use **file:///E:/Work...** prefix.

```
clusters.save(sc, "file:///E:/Work/Python1/work/spark/anomalydetectionspark/test/spark-warehouse")
```

Comment: can you share full stacktrace again?

Comment: The directory path that is coming with error, is there in your machine? if not then create it.

Answer (score 0):

The deploy mode has to be "client" for this to work, otherwise the "local path" passed in has to be found on the server which will not have a path that looks like a Windows path.  If the deploy mode is "client", then care must be taken that the save is not occurring in a parallelized code block which will be executing on worker and again will not have this path.  See:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html